# Is ReadWrite permission now necessary to save CustomProperties of an item in an Outlook Addin?

Tags: outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

The Outlook Addin doc [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook/office.customproperties?view=outlook-js-preview#saveasync-callback--asynccontext-) specifies only ReadItem permission is necessary to saveAsync the customProperties. Since few weeks, an erros occurs: save is not possible and says in console it needs more "rights" to be performed. If I change the manifest to ReadWrite permission, and redeploy the addin, saveAsync method works. But it means we have to redeploy our addin on each and every user...

Is it a bug in Office.js or the documentation which is outdated ?

Comment: Can you please share the exact error string ? Is the error consistent ?

Comment: In which platform do you see the error ? Have you faced the issue in multiple platforms ?

Comment: Detailed console message : " Uncaught Error: Elevated permission is required to call the method: 'item.saveCustomProperties'. " I get this issue on Outlook on the web, and Outlook Desktop 2016 too. @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT

Comment: We are able to repro the issue. Thanks for reporting it. It has been put on our backlog. We unfortunately have no timelines to share at this point.

Comment: Sybic2001, you can deploy add-ins administratively, which you can do through UI or powershell.  Here is powershell: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/enterprise/use-the-centralized-deployment-powershell-cmdlets-to-manage-add-ins .  There may be other reasons why you will need to re-deploy a manifest in the future, but also make sure to increase the version number in the manifest when you do.